# Как сохранить состояние fragment при использовании replace?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, fragment-transaction

У меня есть экран на нем контейнер для фрагментов, и пара кнопок для переключения между ними.
Во втором фрагменте есть текст, картинка и кнопка, по нажатию на кнопку текст и картинка меняются.
Если я переключаюсь обратно на фрагмент_1, а затем снова на фрагмент_2, картинка и текст остаются старыми. Вот мой код:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.d("LogFr", "Start App")

        val fragmentManger = supportFragmentManager
        val transaction = fragmentManger.beginTransaction()
        transaction.add(R.id.frgmCont, Fragment1(), "frag1")
        transaction.commit()
    }

    fun onClick(v: View) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        when (v.id) {
            R.id.btnFr1 -> {
                transaction.replace(R.id.frgmCont, Fragment1(), "frag1").addToBackStack(null)
                Log.i("LogFr", "First Fr")
            }
            R.id.btnFr2 ->  {
                transaction.replace(R.id.frgmCont, Fragment2(), "frag2").addToBackStack(null)
                Log.i("LogFr", "Second Fr")
            }
        }
        transaction.commit()
    }
}

   class Fragment1 : Fragment() {
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null)
        }
    }

class Fragment2 : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false)

            val fr2_txt: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.fr2_txt) as TextView
            val doSome: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.doSome) as Button
            fr2_txt.text = (2 + 2).toString()

            doSome.setOnClickListener {
                fr2_txt.text = (2 + 5 + 7).toString()
                fr2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_2)
            }

        return view
    }
}
```

Как сделать так что бы состояние фрагмента сохранялось?

Comment: Создайте фрагменты один раз и "переключайте" их, сохраняя ссылки на экземпляры. Сейчас вы их каждый раз новые создаете.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja вот так? Я добавляю var fragment2: Fragment2? = null
   , дальше в onCreate fragment2 = Fragment2(), и в onClick fr2_tran.replace(R.id.frgmCont, fragment2!!, "frag2").addToBackStack(null).commit() и тоже самое для первого

Comment: Да, можно так, только транзакции одной достаточно.